# PhoneGap screenshot plugin return base64 encoded string (iPhone)

Tags: cordova

I'm using PhoneGap & Sencha Touch to develop an app. I'm trying to get the app to take a screenshot of the current view and save that image to the photo album but also to  return a base64 encoded string, which we'll use to share & email the image. I can't get the code to return the base64 encoded string. Can anyone see anything wrong in the code?

http://app.kodery.com/profile/360
ScreenShot.m the jsCallBack doesn't seem to receive anything.

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Thanks

Prad

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to help you if you put your code in the question rather than on another site.
I don't think this line is correct:

```
 jsCallBack = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@("%@");", successCallback, encodedString ];
```

The quotes around stringWithFormat are not correct, not sure if this is a problem with the tool you're pasting your code into, or the code itself. 
Also what is the size of imageData 
and what happens if you do an NSLog()  for encodedString:  NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64EncodedString];
Is there actually data there and it's not making it back to your JS? Or is their no data in the native code?